# Preventing function from being invoked twice when binding in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, binding, backbone.js

When either of two attributes ("a" or "b") change in my Backbone model, I'd like to calculate a third attribute "c":

```
initialize: function() {
  this.bind("change:a", this.calculateC);
  this.bind("change:b", this.calculateC);
},

calculateC: function() {
  this.attributes.c = ...
}
```

What is a good way of preventing c from being calculated twice if both a and b are set on the model simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes will not be set simultaneously, they will be set one at time so you need to see both events. The [relevant code looks like this](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone.js):

```
// Set a hash of model attributes on the object, firing `"change"` unless you
// choose to silence it.
set : function(attrs, options) {
  // ...

  // Update attributes.
  for (var attr in attrs) {
    var val = attrs[attr];
    if (!_.isEqual(now[attr], val)) {
      now[attr] = val;
      // ...
      if (!options.silent) this.trigger('change:' + attr, this, val, options);
    }
  }

  // Fire the `"change"` event, if the model has been changed.
  if (!alreadyChanging && !options.silent && this._changed) this.change(options);
```

You can see that one of the attributes is set, then its change event is triggered, then the process is repeated for the next attribute. If you only want one event, then you should bind only to the whole model's change event.

For completeness I should mention that the interface documentation for [`Model#set`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-set) doesn't specify any particular behavior as to when the individual change events will be triggered, it only says that they will be triggered.

Comment: OK, so you'd suggest doing this.bind("change", this.calculateC) and then checking if ("a" or "b" in changedAttributes)? Thanks. /D

Comment: @dani: I'd suggest that you bind to `change:a` and `change:b` and not worry about it. Your intent is to know when `a` or `b` change so binding to the individual events exactly matches what you're trying to do. If your computation is very expensive then binding only to the overall `change` event would make sense but you're better off not worrying too much about optimizing something until you know it is a problem.

Comment: OK, thanks. I tend to optimize too early ... I'll leave it as you say as it's at least logically accurate ...

Comment: @dani: Optimizing correct code is much easier than correcting optimized code :)